# Mixed log in the Java process

Tags: java, logging

I found some mixed log in the Java process, something like:

```
2014-11-09 11:55:24,087 HTTP xxxxxxxxx.Pool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:607) [jetty-util-9.1.0.v20131115.jar:9.1.0.v20131115]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:536) [jetty-util-9.1.0.v20131115.jar:9.1.0.v20131115]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_51]
```

**xxxxxxxxx** means the log recorded in our Java code, and the next is the `RuntimeException` by the server runtime.

Why the log is mixed together ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen if multiple threads try to write to the same log file at the same time.

Are both messages created by the same logging framework? Using the same appender?
If not, the output most likely lacks synchronization.

Comment: Thanks. Some of them use logback and slf4j, the others use the default (JDK logging framework in the third party code, I guess).

Comment: If it's not a big problem, I'd just leave it. If it is, maybe have seperate files for each system. Easier than trying to make them work together.